# Is it safe to read Android asset file with FileChannel?

Tags: android, android-assets

I need to read binary file from `asset` folder in my app, and the way I'm trying to do it is by obtaining `Channel`:

```
AssetFileDescriptor assetFd = context.getAssets().openFd("file.db");
FileChannel fileChan = assetFd.createInputStream().getChannel();
```

The problem is that `AssetManager, AssetFileDescriptor` are very poorly documented classes and behave in unpredicted manner (as it seems to me). For example, if you will try to obtain `fileChan.position()` immediately after code above you won't get 0, in my case it'll be 976. After digging through StackOverflow I found out that it's normal behaviour and you need to be aware that assets are compressed into some internal binary form and `AssetFileDescriptor` isn't real file descriptor. 
In my case I have a file structure with absolute byte positions stored in a header, so it seems like to read it properly I also need take into account `assetFd.getStartOffset()`.

Also I've got zero clue about method `AssetFileDescriptor.createInputStream` behaviour after reading its doc:

> This will either return a full asset `AssetFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream`, or an underlying `ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream` depending on whether the the object represents a complete file or sub-section of a file.

Lack of understanding whole picture and documentation makes me nervous about using this approach.

Should I be worried about `AssetFileDescriptor.createInputStream` behaviour when reading big files (over 1mb)? Is it safe to use `Channels` when reading asset files?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why cannot you use an InputStream? you need a random access?

Comment: it will be damn slow,  you know that?

Comment: Do you mean general performance difference between sequential and random? Or something else? If so, is it so bad? I'm going to use this code in IntentService

Comment: i mean reading in asset file,  can't you copy the file to the normal file system?

Comment: Okay, I can, but why do you think it would be super slow to read from asset file?

Comment: "and you need to be aware that assets are compressed into some internal binary form and AssetFileDescriptor isn't real file "

Comment: As I understand they are bundled into one binary file and AssetFileDescriptor is something like a pointer to the range of bytes from particular asset file.

Comment: and everything is placed in a zip file

Comment: Now that makes sense.

Comment: just get input stream, copy the file and use RandomAccessFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to deal with assets is to copy them to the internal or external storage and then read them with whatever method you want.
Thanks to @pskink for help!